# Result set to nested Vector?

Tags: java, vector, resultset

I'm sorry this may seem a bit basic, but I can't get my head into it today. I have this Vector and I want to fill it with the Results from a ResultSet which looks like:

```
column1, column2, column3, column4, column5

Vector<Vector<String>> myVector = new Vector<Vector<String>>();

           while (rs.next()) {
                            String column1 = rs.getString(1);
                            String column2 = rs.getString(2);
                            String column3 = rs.getString(3);
                            String column4 = rs.getString(4);
                            String column5 = rs.getString(5);
                            myVector.put(column1, column2, column3, column4, column5);
```

Is this the correct way to do it?

TIA

Comment: Since this does not compile, as Vector does not have a `put` method, I would suggest that no, it is not correct.

Comment: To answer your question, we would need to understand why you have a Vector of Vectors and if that is truly your intention.

Comment: It makes sense if he wants an "anonymous" copy of the table data, as opposed to a "typed" copy where he would use a bean instead of the inner collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html

`Vector` implements the `List` interface, so it has `add()`, not `put()`. AFAIK there are no collections in Java that support inserting elements with varargs, so you have to call it once per string:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    Vector v = new Vector<>();
    v.add(rs.getString(1));
    v.add(rs.getString(2));
    v.add(rs.getString(3));
    v.add(rs.getString(4));
    v.add(rs.getString(5));
    myVector.add(v);
}
```

It would be better to use `ArrayList` instead of `Vector` though, unless you need synchronization (and even then, there are better ways to do it).

Edit: the best (IMO) way to do it would be:

```
List<String[]> l = new ArrayList<>();

while (rs.next()) l.add(new String[] {
        rs.getString(1),
        rs.getString(2),
        rs.getString(3),
        rs.getString(4),
        rs.getString(5)
    });
```

Comment: Just as an FYI, Guava provides a varargs for creating Lists: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#newArrayList(E...)

Comment: @JohnB (referred to the vararg) I don't like it very much though: I understand the commodity, but it doesn't seem a very clean approach to me.

Comment: Thank you Viruzzo, I know its not the best way but sometimes fudging is required! I'll know for next time.